# Quartz.net How to set MisfireInstruction on trigger

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, misfire-instruction

In Quartz 1.0.x it was possible so set a MisfireInstruction on the trigger by simply setting it:

```
trigger.MisfireInstruction = MisfireInstruction.CronTrigger.DoNothing;
```

We upgraded the Quartz version to 2.3.2 and it's not possible to set it like this anymore because `trigger.MisfireInstruction` has no setter anymore.

How is it possible to set the MisfireInstruction on a trigger now?

I tried to recreate the trigger with a TriggerBuilder like this:

```
trigger = trigger.GetTriggerBuilder()...
```

but I couldn't find a MisfireInstruction-Method on the TriggerBuilder too.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour has changed with version 2, I guess.
`MisfireInstruction` is now a read-only property and it is set using the builder as you can see in the [codebase](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/045344fe21cbdb2229cb6ac496652941a275e61b/src/Quartz/CronScheduleBuilder.cs#L276).

Now you can set the the `MisfireInstruction` using the `TriggerBuilder`:

```
ITrigger myTrigger = TriggerBuilder
    .Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "myGroup")
    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 1/5 * ? *", x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
    .Build();
```

You can use a few options:

you can use these options:

- WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing
- WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed
- WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires

A really good article with a good explanation can be found [here](https://dzone.com/articles/quartz-scheduler-misfire).

Comment: Cool this worked! Thank you :-) I'll upvote you tomorrow since I have no votes left at the moment :)

Comment: Glad I've helped, xeraphim. A lot of things have changed since version 1.x. If you want to want to find out more about the new features and implementation you can find a lot of good articles on Jay Vilalta's [blog](http://jayvilalta.com/blog/). It's a must to read for quartz.net users. Cheers.